# Solved - sudo into user instead of root with rundeck

Tags: sudo, sudoers

i'm configuring a server for some bioinfo analysis on Centos7 and i installed rundeck.
Rundeck seems to launch scripts as its own account name and i decided to use the sudo bypass to make it access my scripts.

using visudo i can make sudo with rundeck change to root having some commands without password.
As soon as i put the user bioinfo instead of root, the system asks for a password for the same commands.

here is the part of the sudoers file :

```bsh
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
bioinfo ALL=(ALL)       ALL
rundeck ALL=(bioinfo)      NOPASSWD:/home/bioinfo/singularity_data/Bionano3.5,/usr/local/bin/singularity,/bin/*
```

i dont know what's different between root and bioinfo as they have the same rights.
Would anyone have an idea on what would make it not working with bioinfo when it works fine with root ?

I tried my configuration running as root

```bsh
su - rundeck
```

and then doing a

```bsh
sudo whoami
```

if root => root
if bioinfo => ask for password

Thank you

Comment: as root  
```bash
-bash-4.2$ which whoami
/bin/whoami
-bash-4.2$ sudo whoami
root
```
as bioinfo  
```bash
-bash-4.2$ which whoami
/bin/whoami
-bash-4.2$ sudo whoami

Nous espérons que vous avez reçu de votre administrateur système local les consignes traditionnelles. Généralement, elles se concentrent sur ces trois éléments :

    #1) Respectez la vie privée des autres.
    #2) Réfléchissez avant d'utiliser le clavier.
    #3) De grands pouvoirs confèrent de grandes responsabilités.

[sudo] Mot de passe de rundeck :
```

Comment: i did as rundeck switch from ALL to bioinfo in the sudoers file

Comment: bioinfo has the exact same configuration as root root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
bioinfo ALL=(ALL)       ALL and thus, why it wouldn't ask for root's password too ?

Comment: i did root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
bioinfo ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL
rundeck ALL=(bioinfo)   NOPASSWD:/home/bioinfo/singularity_data/Bionano3.5,/usr/local/bin/singularity,/bin/*
and the result is the same, sudo whoami asks for a password

Comment: and bioinfo is in the group wheel too as root

Comment: done, let's go on the next answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the user `bioinfo` to be able to [run sudo commands without typing in a password](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-sudo-without-password-on-centos-linux/) you need to modify the `bioinfo` entry in sudoers to include `NOPASSWD:`

```
bioinfo ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

> Please note that doing this allows the user to run any sudo command without having to type the password in.

If the user is a member of a group (%wheel or %users for example) that is also specified in sudoers, the last entry takes precedence - so put this entry underneath.

If you are want one user to be able to run things as another user without needing a password:

```
rundeck ALL=(bioinfo)      NOPASSWD:/home/bioinfo/singularity_data/Bionano3.5,/usr/local/bin/singularity,/bin/*
```

then you need to invoke commands in the format `sudo -u bioinfo <cmd>` otherwise it thinks you're still trying to invoke as root

Comment: I did so and nothing seems to have changed. i su - rundeck as root, i end up in a bash as rundeck, i do sudo whoami and it asks for a password

Comment: so that's why when i put root as sudo for rundeck i have all the rights i see... that's kinda bad for security isn't it ?

Comment: i have root then %wheel then bioinfo then rundeck, bioinfo has NOPASSWD: ALL and still asks for a password after a su - rundeck as root and then sudo whoami

Comment: But one thing i dont get is that bioinfo is supposed to be able to do all the commands rundeck will do without using sudo at any time. Why should i set that bioinfo has a need for a NOPASSWD ?

Comment: you need to run the command as `sudo -u bioinfo whoami`

Comment: this seems to work ! but then again the sudoers file only tells what rundeck as the right to use without password ?

Comment: Dude(if you are a man) you are the BEST ! thank you so much !

Comment: Sorry - it took me a while to spot you had `(bioinfo)` rather than `(ALL)` in the `rundeck` sudoers line!

Comment: Don't be sorry, you helped me so much, my boss, when i told him the solution told me he knew but he didn't think about it... so thank you so much and sorry i dont have enough karma to upvote your answer.

Comment: That's ok - I like figuring stuff out like this more than getting points. You've marked it as the accepted answer anyway - that's plenty reward enough!